# prlimit causes error 'Argument list too long' with some resource limits

Tags: process-management

my issue is this: `prlimit -t5 echo foo` works fine (cpu limit) but

`prlimit -s5 echo foo` (stack size limit)
`prlimit -v5000 echo foo` (address space limit)

both return: `prlimit: failed to execute echo: Argument list too long`

My system is linuxmint version 19, `prlimit -V` returns 'from util-linux 2.31.1'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution: from prlimit's man2 page (https://linux.die.net/man/2/prlimit):

> this limit also determines the amount of space used for the process's command-line arguments

since this limit is given in bytes, 5 or even 500 bytes are not enough to pass the argument `foo`